# Возникла ошибка: undefined: IsLetter

Tags: golang

Я хочу проверить сообщение на наличие в нем знака вопроса и заглавных букв алфавита.

```golang
package bob

import "strings"
import "fmt"

// Hey should have a comment documenting it.
func Hey(remark string) string {
    remark = fmt.Sprintf(strings.TrimSpace(remark))
    if strings.HasSuffix(remark, "?") && IsLetter(strings.ToUpper(remark)) == true {
        return "string1"
    }

    return "string2"
}
```

Возникает ошибка в одном из условий: `undefined: IsLetter`. Что мне нужно исправить, чтобы обнаружить `IsLetter`?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду [функция](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsLetter) из пакета `unicode`, то так и пишите:

```golang
/* … */ && unicode.IsLetter(/* … */
```

Соответственно, надо добавить импорт:

```golang
import "unicode"
```

Comment: unicode.IsLetter (func (r rune)) принимает в аргументы функцию.Как эту функцию (unicode.IsLetter) использовать к строке?

Comment: Вы по моей ссылке ходили? Оно принимает один [_rune_](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#rune). Если вам нужно проверить, что все руны в строке являются буквами, пройдитесь в цикле.